# Unable to deploy React App to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages

After adding the *home, predeploy and deploy* values to *package.JSON* and running `npm run deploy`, the *build* folder was created successfully but the build was unable to be published.
I got this error

```
cloning into 'node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\github.com.okafohenry!birthday-list-keeper-react-app-.git'...
fatal: unable to access https://github.com.okafohenry/birthday-list-keeper-react-app-.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com.okafohenry

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! birthdaylistkeeper@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the birthdaylistkeeper@1.0.0 deploy script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have been on this for a while now, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The url seems to be wrong.

It should be https://github.com/okafohenry/birthday-list-keeper-react-app-.git/